# Issue with file upload in Web API 2 other then html form post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Issue with file upload in Web API 2

While i upload file with form post this work file but while i am sending same information from Rest Client like Postman in Google Chrome or posting file information with Android or iOS application Web Api 2 code is not detecting file multipart/form-post

**Following is my html code**

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/api/feedback">
    <input type="text" name="Scope" placeholder="Scope" value="feedback">
    <input type="text" name="Lang" placeholder="Lang" value="en">
    <input type="text" name="Collection" placeholder="Collection" value="7b22437573746f6d65724964223a392c2253657276696365526571756573744964223a312c224174746974756465223a332e322c22576f726b457468696373223a342e322c2248796769656e65223a352c22416d6f757450616964223a333132332e327d">
    <input type="file" name="Photo1" placeholder="Photo1">
    <input type="file" name="Photo2" placeholder="Photo2">
    <input type="file" name="Signature" placeholder="Signature">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**This .Net Web Api 2 Code**

```
        public async Task<Result> Post()
    {
        var model = new ApiData();
        var result = new Result();
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            try
            {
                string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/temp");
                var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

                var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body
                // Read the form data and return an async task.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                // This illustrates how to get the form data.
                foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                {
                    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                    {
                        if (key.Equals("Scope"))
                            model.Scope = val;
                        if (key.Equals("Lang"))
                            model.Lang = val;
                        if (key.Equals("Collection"))
                            model.Collection = val;
                    }

                }
                if (!model.Scope.Equals("feedback", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    result.Text = "Missing Scope.";
                else
                {
                    var Util = new Utils();
                    model.Collection = Util.ToString(model.Collection);
                    var _Feedback = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Feedback>(model.Collection);
                    try
                    {
                        // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
                        foreach (var file in provider.FileData)
                        {
                            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                            string BaseUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/assets/feedback/");
                            string oldFile = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
                            string NewName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Util.NewGuid, Path.GetExtension(oldFile));
                            if (file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.ToLower().Contains("photo"))
                            {
                                _Feedback.Photos = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Feedback.Photos) ? NewName : _Feedback.Photos + "," + NewName;
                                fileInfo.MoveTo(BaseUrl + NewName);
                            }
                            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Feedback.Signatures) && file.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.ToLower().Contains("signature"))
                            {
                                _Feedback.Signatures = NewName;
                                fileInfo.MoveTo(BaseUrl + NewName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    if (Util.IsRequired(_Feedback.CustomerId)
                            && Util.IsRequired(_Feedback.ServiceRequestId)
                            && Util.IsRequired(_Feedback.Attitude)
                            && Util.IsRequired(_Feedback.WorkEthics)
                            && Util.IsRequired(_Feedback.Hygiene)
                            )
                    {
                        var feedback = new Feedback()
                        {
                            CustomerId = _Feedback.CustomerId,
                            ServiceRequestId = _Feedback.ServiceRequestId,
                            Attitude = _Feedback.Attitude,
                            WorkEthics = _Feedback.WorkEthics,
                            Hygiene = _Feedback.Hygiene,
                            AmoutPaid = _Feedback.AmoutPaid,
                            Photos = _Feedback.Photos,
                            Signatures = _Feedback.Signatures,
                            Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            Updated = DateTime.UtcNow
                        };

                        db.Feedbacks.Add(feedback);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        if (feedback.Id != default(int))
                        {
                            result.Success = true;
                            result.Text = "Success";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Text = "Required Parameters missing.";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result.Text = "Error";
            }
        }
        else
            result.Text = "Signature or photo missing";
        return result;
    }
```

This is Postmen request

[image]

> Exposing post request in Fiddler Client i have seen that while posting using html form post there is boundary in multipart/form-data; although there is no boundary in Postman or other RestClient.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a Postman [bug](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/576).

To summarize, if you set the Content-Type header with Postman, it seems to override the default browser functionality and not add the boundary. Most the time this is a good thing, but not for multipart/form-data since we need the browser to add the boundary for us. Try removing the Content-Type header. When sending the actual Post, the browser will automatically add the proper header and create the boundary.

Your WebApi code looks fine. Your if check will just be false.

```
//This will be false since it's a malformed request.
if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
```

Comment: #ManOVision 
What will be the alter option for

//This will be false since it's a malformed request.
if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see exactly what the request looks like from postman or your mobile clients? Your controller code looks just fine so it's a client issue not constructing a proper HTTP request.

Comment: Yes i have used fiddler and observe the request body everything is fine don't what my developer missing. Now at least Android Developer able to post image but with similar approach iOS Developer unable to to post the image

Error **The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.**

Comment: Sounds like the iOS guy is issuing a header of Accept: multipart/form-data rather than a Content-Type: multipart/form-data. This error is your API saying the client requesting this resource asked for multipart/form-data to be returned and I don't know how to return that.

Comment: I don't think so, following code has been used by that developer

`
    //Set Params
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    

    //Create boundary, it can be anything
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";
    
    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
`

Comment: Well, time for an old trusty friend...add this to the top of your method `HttpContext.Current.Request.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/request.txt"), true);` and then try your upload again from iOS. This will show you the actual request your server is seeing. Make sure that path exists and your api can write files to it. You can timestamp your file name to so you can test different clients.

Comment: In some clients, if you don't specify an Accept header `*/*` gets added automatically. It could be that iOS is defaulting the Accept header to whatever the Content-Type is if you don't specify. I don't know iOS well enough to know what the defaults are, but I've had some trouble with C# defaults biting me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old post but I think this could help someone who has the same issue. In postman remove Content-Type header. The request will go through fine.